# User with Contribute rights - weird Access Denied issue

Tags: access-denied, check-in

1. Users are in a SharePoint Group
2. SP group has contribute rights (without delete) to a library
3. users can upload and fill out the metadata
4. They get Access Denied after clicking okay on the metadata screen
5. File is check out to the users (however, file is loaded and metadata are populated)

I am bit clueless. Any idea why the access denied and check in issue

The special Permission "Contribute without Delete" does have "Browse User Information" and "Use Remote Interfaces" checked.

note: sp 2010 farm

Comment: Is versioning turned on?

Comment: Yes versioning is enabled for Major only. why ?

Comment: I can't repeat it now, but I know in the past a permissions issue kept users without delete permissions from overwriting an existing version. It was like overwriting the version had to first delete that version. It's worth seeing if the issue still exists if you turn off versioning.